# React app displaying blank page on github pages

Tags: reactjs, github

I've been trying to deploy a react app on github pages but it keeps rendering a blank page. I've tried a few different things (changing https to http, starting a new repo) each time I've made a git push and waited a while for github to build it but even after hours there is no change.

https://github.com/Michael-ET/Reddit-reader

Comment: I fixed it by editing "Privacy": "true" to "privacy":"false" in package.json

Answer (score 1):

You [changed the `homepage` property in `package.json`](https://github.com/Michael-ET/Reddit-reader/commit/ec11e8bd369b05766eb8bb0cabc72dc89f962853#diff-7ae45ad102eab3b6d7e7896acd08c427a9b25b346470d7bc6507b6481575d519), but never re-built your app and pushed changes in the build to your [`gh-pages` branch](https://github.com/Michael-ET/Reddit-reader/tree/gh-pages):

The pathname is still outdated in [`index.html`](https://github.com/Michael-ET/Reddit-reader/commits/gh-pages/index.html).

Comment: See https://github.com/Michael-ET/Reddit-reader/pull/1

Comment: Hi, Thanks for checking out my problem. I actually just rebuilt and redeployed it. I thought i had done this before but its working now. One possible reason might be that i changed the privacy property in package. json to "false"